# Is there any way for a website to differentiate between Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome's rendering engine?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, media-queries, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge has a bunch of issues when it comes to rendering my website as it's adapted to Firefox and Chrome, so I decided to add a pop-up message suggesting switching to Firefox or Chrome.

However, I've noticed that a lot of websites can't tell apart between Chrome and Microsoft Edge because its render engine is very similar to Webkit. Some mistakenly identify Edge as Chrome.

Is there some sort of media query, or JS hack, that could distinguish between the two browsers?
Since it's still a very recent browser, it'd be great if there was a definite media query, rather than a temporary one.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but Microsoft Edge adheres to the same web standards as the latest Firefox and Chrome. If it's not working in Edge there is something wrong with your website, not the browser.

Comment: "_If it's not working in Edge there is something wrong with your website_"; rofl, best joke all day... http://caniuse.com/#compare=edge+13,firefox+45,chrome+49

Comment: For some odd reason, Edge doesn't scale SVG graphics properly, even with viewBox, width and height set. I'm stunned because [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) mentions that it should be the best workaround. My menu looks like this in different browsers: [image](http://i.imgur.com/AL0qvXv.png). Sorry about the comments, though.

Comment: @MrMisterMan you are wrong. Edge has more approach to standards than the old IE, but is the same story everyday, while microsoft can't adapt his browsers to standards it's impossible to say that Edge has the same behaviour than chrome or firefox. That's a lie. Or as dandavis said, the best joke all day.

Comment: Edge is one thing, but if FF and Ch don't match, you need to do some validating and housekeeping...

Comment: I remember when IE11 is released, that the UA string have "Mozilla" inside it, just for unable developers to make this kind of checks, but in practice IE11 still a very bad browser.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: all user agents strings have included `Mozilla` for the last 17 years... http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/

Comment: @dandavis so there's another string. I remember that I have that issue in a project 4 years ago. It works in IE10 but when IE11 is released all goes to trash.

Comment: Yeah, I see, the issue was that removes the `MSIE` string and it turns to `Trident`. Thank you for the link, remembrances are sometimes good and sometimes a hell

Comment: Oh, great, more Microsoft salt. I'm just going to leave this here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/29074?m=27957764#27957764

Comment: fwiw, see https://www.browserstack.com/.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some sort of media query, or JS hack, that could distinguish
>   between the two browsers?

Since only chrome , chromium and canary implement [`requestFileSystem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem#Browser_Compatibility) can try

```
if ("webkitRequestFileSystem" in window) {
  // do chrome stuff
}
```

Comment: what if chrome un-prefixes `animation`, like they did with `borderRadius` et al ?

Comment: Nope, Microsoft Edge maps webkit prefixes to their unprefixed aliases specifically to defeat these checks.

Comment: @dandavis There are alternatives. The one property that other browsers do not currently have is `requestFileSystem`

Comment: @BoltClock See updated post